# Mobile and desktop detector

Tags: php, html, css

I have a slider, in each slider there is one video, is it possible when entering from a mobile device, it shows a picture, and if enter with desktop to show video?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What did you try to accomplish it?

Comment: Because in mobile version website working so slow, and I want to reduce the load

Comment: Are you using the `<video>` element? If so, you can accomplish this without resorting to user agent sniffing. For example, you could display a `poster` for the image, include your video source as a `data-*` attribute (probably `data-source`) and use the native DOM API's `matchMedia` method to swap out the `data-source` for a live `src` at desktop resolutions... easy-peasy.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the desktop version slow?

Comment: @Peter you misunderstand me, conversely,  I want to speed up

Comment: But you want to speed it up only on mobile devices. That's silly. Make it fast for everyone.

Comment: @Peter cuz in desktop version speed is 79, in mobile 37, so i decided if i remove video slider and replace it with picture, speed will increase)

Comment: I have no clue what those numbers mean, but I don't see why increasing both of them is a bad thing (assuming bigger numbers are better). My point is, you arbitrarily decided that all mobile devices are slower than desktops. That's wrong. LTE is faster than my landline and my phone has a faster CPU than my old PC.

Comment: @Peter it's for SEO "Search engine optimization"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function to detect device

```
public function detectDevice(){

$userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$devicesTypes = array(
    "computer" => array("msie 10", "msie 9", "msie 8", "windows.*firefox", "windows.*chrome", "x11.*chrome", "x11.*firefox", "macintosh.*chrome", "macintosh.*firefox", "opera"),
    "tablet"   => array("tablet", "android", "ipad", "tablet.*firefox"),
    "mobile"   => array("mobile ", "android.*mobile", "iphone", "ipod", "opera mobi", "opera mini"),
    "bot"      => array("googlebot", "mediapartners-google", "adsbot-google", "duckduckbot", "msnbot", "bingbot", "ask", "facebook", "yahoo", "addthis")
);
foreach($devicesTypes as $deviceType => $devices) {           
    foreach($devices as $device) {
        if(preg_match("/" . $device . "/i", $userAgent)) {
            $deviceName = $deviceType;
        }
    }
}
return ucfirst($deviceName);
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191493/discussion-between-fokrule-and-arsen-ospanov).

Comment: Note: You should not blindly trust what's in `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`. The string can be manipulated by the client.

Comment: Also note user agents can and do change over time.